# How to restart vim in the state it is?

Tags: input-devices

So i am using abduco.
I have an abduco session and lets say I reattach to it at a later point. Then, for some reason, I am not able to move around in vim. Specifically the mouse and the keys stop working. This can probably be fixed in abduco (I don't know though). But I did notice that if I quit vim and started it again then I was able to navigate using the keys and mouse. So I wanted to know if there was a quick way to restart vim with all the windows as they are.

Comment: `:mksession` and `:source Session.vim` ?

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 5):

The best move here is to use sessions. As @Maxim Kim notes in the comments, one way to do that is with `:mksession` and `:source Session.vim`.

But I'll show you two other tricks.

1. `vim` has a `-S` flag that can be used to source an arbitrary vimscript file; it *defaults* to `Session.vim`—so this means you can just type `vim -S` in your shell to start back from a session!
2. I actually use a (bash) function in my shell for this same trick:

```
vs () { 
  if (($# > 0)); then
    local session="$1"
    shift
    vim "$@" -S "$session"
  else
    vim -S
  fi
}
```

3. I use tpope’s [Obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) for easy session management. It has a host of benefits, but the main ones include

   - automatic session updating,
   - saves only the relevant stuff
   - a statusline indicator to let me know when I'm actually using a obsession session

From its README (10th March 2020):

> - Instead of making me remember to capture the session immediately before exiting Vim, allow me to do it at any time, and automatically re-invoke `:mksession` immediately before exit.
> - Also invoke `:mksession` whenever the layout changes (in particular, on `BufEnter`), so that even if Vim exits abnormally, I'm good to go.
> - If I load an existing session, automatically keep it updated as above.
> - If I try to create a new session on top of an existing session, don't refuse to overwrite it. Just do what I mean.
> - If I pass in a directory rather than a file name, just create a `Session.vim` inside of it.
> - Don't capture options and maps. Options are sometimes mutilated and maps just interfere with updating plugins.
>
> Use `:Obsess` (with optional file/directory name) to start recording to a session file and `:Obsess!` to stop and throw it away. That's it. Load a session in the usual manner: `vim -S`, or `:source` it.
>
> There's also an indicator you can put in `'statusline'`, `'tabline'`, or `'titlestring'`. See `:help obsession-status`.

Comment: Answer could use more details. Link to plug-in? What does this plug-in do? What's the advantage it offers over manually managing your sessions with `:mksession`? Any caveats to be aware of?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious!  I haven't been a user of sessions or of this plug-in, so I'd relish the opportunity to get your take on it, since I already knew you're a fan.

Comment: @delete-vote can probably be retracted now?

Comment: Thanks! (I haven't voted to delete it... Don't see that vote, myself.)

Comment: @filbranden perhaps only I can see it bc I wrote the post? Anyway, not worried :P